# Is it unsafe to send pointers on a channel? If yes, then why?

Tags: go

I came across this reddit comment saying that one should not pass pointers to channel or a struct with pointers fields but it didn't give enough explaination

Comment: Which reddit comment? Sounds like the author is probably confused.

Comment: will need to find out, if I do will ping you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to send pointers on a channel if you're being careful about it and understand that what comes out on the other end is still a pointer to the same data and not a copy.

That is, if you're using the channel to communicate between two goroutines, you ought to be careful about accessing the pointer from two different goroutines at the same time - because that could be a data race (if one of the goroutines is modifying the underlying data). However, if this is taken into account then there is no safety issue.